# Update Different Object Based on Conditions in Apex

Tags: apex, soql, salesforcedx

I have two custom Objects `Enroll_Family_Members__c`  and `Family_Members__c`.

If the `enroll = Y` then i have to pass the  recordId in `Enroll_Family_Members__c`  table and Update the Fields, Else have to Pass in `Family_Members__c` table.

**Note:** Both Objects has Same set of Fields.

```
if(enroll =='Y'){
                Enroll_Family_Members__c con = [select Id from Enroll_Family_Members__c  where Id=:recId];
            }else{
                Family_Members__c con = [select Id from Family_Members__c where Id=:recId ];  
            }
```

```
  con.FirstName__c = firstName;
con.LastName__c = lastName;
```

getting `Variable does not exist: con` compiler error, It's because of using `con` outside the If condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a generic sObject outside of the if-else block:

```
sObject con;
if(enroll =='Y'){
    con = [select Id from Enroll_Family_Members__c  where Id=:recId];
} else {
    con = [select Id from Family_Members__c where Id=:recId ];  
}
con.put('FirstName__c',firstName);
con.put('LastName__c',lastName);
```

Note the use of sObject.put to set a field dynamically.

When you have a variable inside an if-else block, they are "scoped" to just that block. You can read more about scope in [Variables](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_variables.htm).